# XPeria L stuck in bootloop after flashing Ressurrection Remix ROM

Tags: recovery-mode, boot-loop, fastboot, twrp

Folks, I unlocked the bootloader and rooted my XPeria L without problems, I then installed TWRP, made a complete backup and tried flashing the Ressurrection Remix ROM. But the phone doesn't boot up and the ROM installed the Cyanogen Recovery atop my TWRP, and now I can't find a way to restore my backup.

I tried flashing the system image again through Flashtool, but it doesn't work. Flashtool returns an error saying "Error Flashing. Aborted".

I then tried to reinstall twrp by connecting the device in fastboot mode to my PC and issuing the command:

fastboot flash recovery recovery.img

But it returns an error message saying "FAILED (remote: Command not allowed).

What can I do to save my device?

Comment: Run `fastboot flash boot recovery.img` and `fastboot reboot` It'll let you to custom recovery once, there you can try _Factory reset, Wipe Cache, Dalvik Cache_ and check if the device boots without any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out a way to do it. As pointed in the comments, I had to flash a new boot image, because for some reason on sony devices (not sure if on all of them) you can't flash a new recovery through fastboot.

So what I did was search for a new XPeria L boot image with twrp, which I found here:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-l/development/twrp-twrp-xperia-l-t2667370

I flashed it through fastboot and booted back to recovery, and then proceeded to restore the backup I made before trying to flash a custom rom. From there I flashed a new rom and now everything is working fine.